# Vim displays OOPS instead of placement/color commands

Tags: shell, unix, vim, environment-variables, solaris

I have a collection of Solaris boxes (5.10/8) on which I operate. When I log into one particular user and start Vim, I do not see the intro message of Vim as it should be. Instead, the message is displayed at the bottom on of the screen and "OOPS" is placed where we might expect to see a new line or any other color command. The problem persists when I start typing. The initial output looks like:

OOPSVIM - Vi IMprovedOOPSversion 7.2OOPSby Bram Moolenaar et al.OOPSVim is open source and freely distributableOOPSBecome a registered Vim user!OOPStype  :help register   for informationOOPStype  :qOOPSto exitOOPStype  :help  or    for on-line helpOOPStype  :help version7   for version infoOOPSRunning in Vi compatible modeOOPStype  :set nocpOOPSfor Vim defaultsOOPStype  :help cp-default for info on thisOOPS

This occurs for all boxes. When I log out and use any other user, calling the same binary, the problem does not appear. I have taken the .vimrc from a different user and copied it to the home directory of the problem user to no avail. I have also tried setting the environment variables to match another user. I've found one post by Googling that says the problem was solved when they recompiled the binary. However, I do not have control or access to do that and I do not think it is a binary issue since all other users can use Vim just fine. Can someone spot what may be the problem?

Comment: try using TERM=vt100, TERM=iris-ansi, TERM=xterm, TERM=linux and the like

Comment: vt100 worked the best, but when I tried to add in colors, it broke a little. I'll keep along this line of thought. It's clear that the TERM is indeed the culprit. If anyone has a suggestion for a TERM, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: Fixed the problem! It wasn't TERM. I checked my environment variables already with a working user, but I just realized the broken user's vim worked correctly on one box. So I did a set > text. Then sourced the text file on machines where vim was broken. Voila! Fixed. POE led me to discover LD_LIBRARY_PATH was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen here:

- http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/term.c
- http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/termlib.c

The `tgoto` function (purpose: decode cm cursor motion string) can fail and return OOPS.

The most likely reason is unsupported TERM environment variable. To get a list of builtin terminal types recognized, try

```
TERM=bogus vim +q
```

It will show a list, and you can pick the one most closely resembling your OS/terminal (*emulator*)

PS. Consider filing a bug on the [`vim-dev` list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#vim-dev) if you think this behaviour affects standard Solaris installations

Comment: I'm Windows using Putty. The TERM is set to xterm. However, I did as you asked and saw the list of available TERM's. I used one of them, but the behavior didn't change. I matched the TERM environment variable to the users that did work and there is no difference.

Comment: I'd inquire on the list and/or file the bug; chances are that your solaris is using nondefault terminal codes unknown to vim. There is a chance that the devs know precisely what to add. I don't remember having this with my OpenSolaris box (nv147)

Comment: Just noticed you fixed it. I bet it was libtermcap or something, but I won't complain if you don't want to find out :)